# PHP and FlashVars communication

Tags: php, flash-builder, parameters, flashvars

Here is a simple problem I need to maintain. I need to pass PHP variable into FlashVars.

```
<param name=FlashVars value='sourceUrl=<?php echo $fileName;?>'>
```

If I use `<param name=FlashVars value='sourceUrl=videoSource'>` where `videoSource = $fileName` and `$fileName` is something like(Video/video.flv) it won't work. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.writeln("<param name=FlashVars value='sourceUrl= \""+videoSource+"\"'>");
```

`videoSource` takes value of `$fileName` this way `var videoSource="<?php echo $fileName;?>";` Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to use

```
 <?php echo urlencode($filename); ?>
```

Dump the flash var in action script - if it appears correctly, then the issue is elsewhere in your action script code. Or in this case it could be a filepath issue or a file permissions issue.

It is unlikely to be an issue with passing the flashvar into flash.

Comment: not working after inspect element with Google chrome it gives exactly what I've written in the html

Comment: Have you tried dumping out the flashvar in action script? What comes through in flash?

Comment: gives the same which is written

Comment: This indicates that it is an issue with your flash code rather than how the param is being passed into flash.